# how to access media_root in py file

Tags: python, url, media

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/blah/djangoproj/abc/abc/media/static/'
```

In random.py file,
how do I access files within MEDIA_ROOT? How should I add media_root to urls.py?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can just import it from your settings.py file

```
from django.conf import settings #or from my_project import settings
print settings.MEDIA_ROOT
```

in urls.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings

urls = (...
(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$'%settings.MEDIA_URL, 'django.views.static.serve', {
        'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
    })
```

Comment: Um, is there a way to set MEDIA_ROOT in relation to STATIC_ROOT? (so i don't have to hardcode the local directory)

Comment: `os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT,settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` ... should be fine for that...